# How to pass a member function to another member function?

Tags: c++, function, member

My problem is about passing a member function from a Class A, to a member function of a Class B:

I tried something like this :

```
typedef void (moteurGraphique::* f)(Sprite);
f draw =&moteurGraphique::drawSprite;
defaultScene.boucle(draw);
```

`moteurGraphique` is A class, `moteurGraphique::drawSprite` is A member function,

`defaultScene` is an instance of B class, and `boucle` is B member function.

All that is called in a member function of A:

```
void moteurGraphique::drawMyThings()
```

I tried different ways to do it, that one seems the more logical to me, but it won't work!
I got:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'f' is being used without being initialized.
```

I think I am doing something wrong, can someone explain my mistake ?

Comment: What compiler are you using which checks such things during runtime?

Comment: You need to post actual code, not "something like this".

Comment: Piece of advice: Have in mind that member functions are bound to objects.

Comment: Do you mean [something like this](http://ideone.com/D3b9oX)?

Comment: Yes Visual C++,

I know that i can do that in other ays, like static functions, but i would like to do like that, Is that even possible ?

Comment: @FabricePalermo yes it's possible, but you need to post an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you need specific help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++11 way:

```
using Function = std::function<void (Sprite)>;

void B::boucle(Function func);
...

A a;
B b;

b.boucle(std::bind(&A::drawSprite, &a, std::placeholders::_1));
```

Comment: That still won't work, i did the c++ normal way , Thanks a lot for trying

Answer (score 2):

Member functions need to be called on objects, so passing the function pointer alone is not enough, you also need the object to call that pointer on. You can either store that object in the class that is going to call the function, create it right before calling the function, or pass it along with the function pointer.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
    } 
};

class Bar
{
public:
    void bar(Foo * obj, void(Foo::*func)(void))
    {
        (obj->*func)();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    Bar b;
    b.bar(&f, &Foo::foo);//output: foo
}
```

Comment: I think i would do like that, because i am affraid, other ways wont works.

I knew that member functions are attached to executed object,but i wanted a way to dynamicly bind that, Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Can't you make drawMyThing a static function if you don't need to instantiate A, and then do something like  :

```
defaultScene.boucle(A.drawMyThing(mySpriteThing));
```

?

Comment: Yes, i could do that easily, but i want to stay dynamic,