# Pass non-static member function to member function of another class

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member, non-static

I have two classes A and B. And I want to call  the member function of class B from class A while passing a member function of A to said function of B. The setting:

```
class B {
    public:
        int dopristep(std::function<int(int,int)> f, double t, double h);
    };

class A {
public:
    
    void run();
    int g(int,int);
    B* mB;
};

void A::run() {

    ires         = mB->dopristep(&g,  T, h)   
}

int A::g(int,int){
//do something
}
```

I tried with `std::bind` and `std::function` definitions. But it didn't work since it requires a static member function somehow.
( I am aware that there are similar questions here. But almost all of them reside these calls in the main or inside only one class) The most similar case I could find which didn't help was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098050/how-to-pass-a-member-function-to-another-member-function).

Can anyone please help me on how I can implement this ?

`ERROR:reference to non-static member function must be called`

Comment: Can you modify `B::func` or is it fixed?

Comment: `int*f()` declares `f` as a non-member function that takes no arguments and return a *pointer* to an `int`. Perhaps you wanted `int (*f)()`? Or considering how you use `func`, perhaps `int (A::*f)(int, int)`?

Comment: B::func is not fixed it was meant as a reference that here I want to pass the function from A. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using generic std::function objects with member functions in one class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582546/using-generic-stdfunction-objects-with-member-functions-in-one-class)

Comment: A pointer to a *non*-member function (like `int (*f)()`) is vastly different from a pointer to a (non-static) member function (like `&A::g`). That's because (non-static) member functions have a hidden first argument that is the `this` pointer. I suggest you use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of function pointers, and use [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of passing functions directly.

Comment: `func` takes a free function pointer, but `A::run` is a member function. Why dont you simply call  `mB->run()`? and please include the error message in the question

Comment: There is no need to have a `std::function` argument. Learn how to pass functors via templates and then using `std::bind` should work.

Comment: I updated the Question with more of the actual code and the Error Message.
@Erlkoenig sadly not since I dont have the namespace in the other class.

Comment: @IllidanS4wantsMonicaback Could you give me an example how to implement this way?

Comment: The problem mentioned by the error message is that you need to fully qualify member function pointers. Instead of `&g` you need to use `&A::g`. But that will lead to other errors, as the `std::function` signature doesn't match that of `A::g`.

Comment: The signatures `int(double, double *, double *, double *)` does not match the one of `g`, so that can't work.

Comment: You can do `mB->dopristep([&] (int a, int b) { return g(a, b); }, T, h);` just as the linked question shows.

Comment: @Erlkoenig updated it since it doesnt matter what I pass there, just wanted to make it simple.

Comment: @Erlkönig thats exactly what fixed it. Thank you! If you make an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7582546/4730685), pass a lambda that calls the function on the enclosing `A` instance:

```
mB->dopristep([&] (int a, int b) { return g(a, b); }, T, h);
```

Additionally, you could modify `dopristep` to accept a functional which will avoid some overhead:

```
template <typename F>
int dopristep(F&& f, double t, double h);
```